# How to avoid duplicating files that goes on an iPad?

Tags: itunes, ios, ipad, books

I would like to upload PDF files on an iPad. After adding them to the iTunes Library (iTunes -> Files -> Add to Library), and syncing, they are uploaded on the iPad, but are also copied locally in ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Books.

Is there a way to prevent the files from being copied in my home directory ? I just want them at two places: an external hard drive, and the iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac: Drag the files into iTunes with the *option* key down and the files won't be copied to your `iTunes Media` folder.

That's the exact result you like.

There is also the option to change it so you don't have to press option key: [image: See this image]

You can press option key after changing that setting to copy it on purpose. (Exact opposite of default setting)

Good luck :)

Comment: OK, thanks, BTW, where in iTunes do you drop the files? I find iTunes very confusing..

Comment: You drag them and you see a blue border around the screen. You can drop them there.

Comment: I don't know in which mode iTunes should be when I drop the pdf file in it, I have no feedback after the drop. What should the top left combo box read ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Do you see a blue border around everything when you drag and drop something into iTunes?

Comment: Yes. There is in fact no problem, I can drop it as long as it's blue. I hope some day a member of the iTunes team at Apple will open a book on user interfaces, and read it.